# tensorflow: Combining to_categorical() with Datasets and map()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In short, I am struggling in trying to convert an image per-pixel category mask in a `tf.data.Dataset` from an integer-class encoding to a one-hot encoding.

Consider the image segmentation tensorflow tutorial example here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation.

The input is an image and the output is a per-pixel integer-labeled category mask.  In their example, the mask has a category value at each pixel represented by an integer: {0, 1, or 2}.

The `train` and `test` variables are of type `tf.data.Dataset`  and each sample is an (image,mask) tuple.

This form of mask/output is consistent with the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss function in the tutorial.  However, I would like to be able to use other loss functions that require a one-hot encoding instead.

I have been attempting to convert the datasets via the `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical()` function using a map() call, ie.:

```py
    def mask_to_categorical(image, mask):
        mask = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(mask,3)
        return image, mask
    
    train = train.map(mask_to_categorical)
```

However, this fails with an error such as:

```py
    {...}/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/np_utils.py:40 to_categorical
        y = np.array(y, dtype='int')

    TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

---

Note:

My searching thus far has pointed towards eager/non-eager issues as one possible cause.  For what it's worth, I verified that I am running in eager mode via:

```py
    >>> print('tf.executing_eagerly() = ', tf.executing_eagerly())
    
    tf.executing_eagerly() =  True
```

Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try modifying your function for the **one-hot encoding** like this:

```
def mask_to_categorical(image, mask):
    mask = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(mask, tf.int32), 3)
    mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)
    return image, mask
```